# Propagating an Oozie coordinator's run date into the workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

**Problem Summary**

When running an Oozie coordinator, I need the workflow to be able to have access to the current date (i.e. the date on which the coordinator is running) in the format `yyyyMMdd`.

**Information**

I have a large Oozie workflow that is initialised by a coordinator.

***coord.properties***

```
nameNode=<namenode>
jobTracker=<jobtracker>:8050

queueName=default
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/project/workflow/lib
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/project/workflow
```

***coordinator.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1" name="wf_scheduler" frequency="${coord:days(1)}" start="2015-01-30T08:50Z" end="2017-01-30T05:00Z" timezone="UTC">
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>${nameNode}/project/workflow</app-path>
         <configuration>
            <property>
               <name>currentDate</name>
               <value>${coord:actualTime()}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
            <name>runDate</name>
            <value>${convertDate(currentDate,"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ","yyyyMMdd")}</value>
            </property>
         </configuration>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

When running this workflow from `job.properties` (i.e. not a coordinator), I have a `runDate=20150125` property in `job.properties`. Obviously when running from a coordinator I need to have `runDate` set each day by the coordinator. This would seem trivial, but I can't find a solution.

I already have an EL function mentioned in `oozie.service.ELService.ext.functions.workflow` which allows me to give a string representing a date, a date format, and the desired output format, and then returns a string date in that format. i.e. `${convertDate("20150125", "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd") = 2015-01-25`. This function works perfectly when running from `job.properties` and my ideal solution would involve being able to use it in coordinator.xml. However, I get the following error when submitting the coordinator:

```
Error: E1004 : E1004: Expression language evaluation error, Unable to evaluate :${convertDate(currentDate,"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mmZ","yyyyMMdd")}:
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that I am aware of the `<dataset>` tags in coordinators, but incorporating them would require a re-write of my workflow, and would create quite a large and unnecessary difference between coordinator and ad-hoc runs. It would be much simpler to keep using my `runDate` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably find it easier to use the built-in EL function `coord:formatTime(String timeStamp, String format)` to convert timestamp formats:

https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.9.2._coord:formatTimeString_ts_String_format_EL_Function_since_Oozie_2.3.2

For example:

```
${coord:formatTime(coord:actualTime(), "yyyyMMdd")}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. Just out of curiosity, do you know why Oozie doesn't allow you to use `coord` functions globally? It seems silly to have had to make my own EL functions!

Comment: I don't know of any powerful reason other than to keep the definitions of workflows and coordinators separated.